# Bookmark issues

Tags: sectioning, bookmarks

I've found this code online, which allows using infinite section levels with the `\level{n}{title}` command.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\level[1]{%
    \ifcase#1\relax\expandafter\chapter\or
        \expandafter\section\or
        \expandafter\subsection\or
        \expandafter\subsubsection\else
        \def\next{\@level{#1}}\expandafter\next
    \fi}
\newcommand{\@level}[1]{%
    \@startsection{level#1}%
        {#1}%
        {\z@}%
        {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
        {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
        {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

\newdimen\@numsdim
\newdimen\@dotsdim
{\normalfont\normalsize
    \sbox\z@{0}\global\@numsdim=\wd\z@
    \sbox\z@{.}\global\@dotsdim=\wd\z@
}

\newdimen\@numindent
\newdimen\@textindent
\setlength{\@numindent}{15pt}
\setlength{\@textindent}{15pt}


\newcounter{level4}[subsubsection]
\@namedef{thelevel4}{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{level4}}
\@namedef{level4mark}#1{}
%\def\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{\dimexpr\@numindent*0\relax}{\dimexpr\@dotsdim*0+\@numsdim*1+\@textindent\relax}}
\def\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{\dimexpr\@numindent*1\relax}{\dimexpr\@dotsdim*1+\@numsdim*2+\@textindent\relax}}
\def\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{\dimexpr\@numindent*2\relax}{\dimexpr\@dotsdim*2+\@numsdim*3+\@textindent\relax}}
\@namedef{l@level4}{\@dottedtocline{4}{\dimexpr\@numindent*3\relax}{\dimexpr\@dotsdim*3+\@numsdim*4+\@textindent\relax}}

\count@=4
\def\@ncp#1{\number\numexpr\count@+#1\relax}
\loop\ifnum\count@<100
    \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
        \noexpand\newcounter{level\@ncp{1}}[level\number\count@]
        \noexpand\@namedef{thelevel\@ncp{1}}{%
            \noexpand\@nameuse{thelevel\@ncp{0}}.\noexpand\arabic{level\@ncp{1}}}
        \noexpand\@namedef{level\@ncp{1}mark}####1{}%
        \noexpand\@namedef{l@level\@ncp{1}}%
            {\noexpand\@dottedtocline%
                {\@ncp{1}}%
                {\dimexpr\@numindent*\@ncp{0}\relax}%
                {\the\dimexpr\@dotsdim*\@ncp{0}+\@numsdim*\@ncp{1}+\@textindent\relax}}}%
    \x
    \advance\count@\@ne
\repeat
\makeatother
```

It works great, but bookmarks of levels greater than 3 are treated like sections.
Here's an example:
[image: Example of wrong bookmarks]

The green one is right (`\level{1}{Preventivo}`) as is treated as section. The red one is wrong (`level{4}{Suddivisione lavoro}`) as is treated as section too.

Any idea about how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should get a warning:

```
Package hyperref Warning: bookmark level for unknown level4 defaults to 0.
```

That means unknown section levels (`level4`, `level5`, ...) are treated with value 0 (`chapter`).

The additional bookmark levels can be defined the following way:

```
\@namedef{toclevel@level4}{4}
\@namedef{toclevel@level5}{5}
...
```

Or inside your loop:

```
\expandafter\edef\csname toclevel@level\the\count@\endcsname{\the\count@}%
```

Also of interest:

- `hyperref` option `bookmarksdepth` to increase the depths of the bookmark hierarchy.
- Levels 4 and 5 are usually `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph`.
- Package `bookmark` is recommended. More options, less LaTeX runs, ...

Test file:

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\level[1]{%
    \ifcase#1\relax\expandafter\chapter\or
        \expandafter\section\or
        \expandafter\subsection\or
        \expandafter\subsubsection\else
        \def\next{\@level{#1}}\expandafter\next
    \fi}
\newcommand{\@level}[1]{%
    \@startsection{level#1}%
        {#1}%
        {\z@}%
        {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
        {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
        {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

\newdimen\@numsdim
\newdimen\@dotsdim
{\normalfont\normalsize
    \sbox\z@{0}\global\@numsdim=\wd\z@
    \sbox\z@{.}\global\@dotsdim=\wd\z@
}

\newdimen\@numindent
\newdimen\@textindent
\setlength{\@numindent}{15pt}
\setlength{\@textindent}{15pt}


\newcounter{level4}[subsubsection]
\@namedef{thelevel4}{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{level4}}
\@namedef{level4mark}#1{}
%\def\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{\dimexpr\@numindent*0\relax}{\dimexpr\@dotsdim*0+\@numsdim*1+\@textindent\relax}}
\def\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{\dimexpr\@numindent*1\relax}{\dimexpr\@dotsdim*1+\@numsdim*2+\@textindent\relax}}
\def\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{\dimexpr\@numindent*2\relax}{\dimexpr\@dotsdim*2+\@numsdim*3+\@textindent\relax}}
\@namedef{l@level4}{\@dottedtocline{4}{\dimexpr\@numindent*3\relax}{\dimexpr\@dotsdim*3+\@numsdim*4+\@textindent\relax}}

\count@=4
\def\@ncp#1{\number\numexpr\count@+#1\relax}
\loop\ifnum\count@<100
    \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
        \noexpand\newcounter{level\@ncp{1}}[level\number\count@]
        \noexpand\@namedef{thelevel\@ncp{1}}{%
        \noexpand\@nameuse{thelevel\@ncp{0}}.\noexpand\arabic{level\@ncp{1}}}
        \noexpand\@namedef{level\@ncp{1}mark}####1{}%
        \noexpand\@namedef{l@level\@ncp{1}}%
            {\noexpand\@dottedtocline%
                {\@ncp{1}}%
                {\dimexpr\@numindent*\@ncp{0}\relax}%
                {\the\dimexpr\@dotsdim*\@ncp{0}+\@numsdim*\@ncp{1}+\@textindent\relax}}}%
    \x
    \expandafter\edef\csname toclevel@level\the\count@\endcsname{\the\count@}%
    \advance\count@\@ne
\repeat
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{
  open,
  depth=8,
  numbered,
}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{8}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{8}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\level0{Chapter A}
\level1{Section B}
\level1{Section C}
\level2{Subsection D}
\level2{Subsection E}
\level3{Subsubsection F}
\level3{Subsubsection G}
\level4{Level 4 H}
\level4{Level 4 I}
\level5{Level 5 J}
\level5{Level 5 K}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]