# \@startsection does not follow the depth?

Tags: sectioning

When typing:

```
\newcommand\subsectionNotIndented{%
  \@startsection{subsectionNotIndented}{3}
  {\z@}% Left indentation
  {2mm plus 1mm minus 1mm}% Space above
  {2mm plus 1mm minus 1mm}% space after label
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries\color{color1}}% font for
}
```

I would expect the section to be of depth 3, i.e. appear like a subsection in the TOC. But it is not the case, not only it appears at the top level, but it also mess-up all remaining TOC entries:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,colorlinks]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\firstname{Foo}
\familyname{bar}
\title{My title}
\address{Adress}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{subsectionNotIndented}
\newcommand\subsectionNotIndented{%
  \@startsection{subsectionNotIndented}{3}
  {\z@}% Left indentation
  {2mm plus 1mm minus 1mm}% Space above
  {2mm plus 1mm minus 1mm}% space after label
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries\color{color1}}% font for
}
\newcounter{subsubsectionNotIndented}
\newcommand\subsubsectionNotIndented{%
  \@startsection{subsubsectionNotIndented}{4}
  {0mm}% Left indentation
  {1mm plus .5mm minus .5mm}% Space above
  {1mm plus .5mm minus .5mm}% space after label
  {\normalfont\normalsize\color{color1}}% font for
}
\newcommand\subsectionNotIndentedmark[1]{}
\newcommand\subsubsectionNotIndentedmark[1]{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\maketitle

\section{Foo}
\subsection{Bar}
\subsection{Baz}

\section{Fooo}
\subsection{Baar}
\subsection{Baaz}

\section{MyFoo}
\subsectionNotIndented{MyBarr}
\subsubsectionNotIndented{MySubBarr}
\subsubsectionNotIndented{MySubBarrr}

\subsectionNotIndented{MyBazz}
\subsubsectionNotIndented{MySuubBarr}
\subsubsectionNotIndented{MySuubBarrr}

\section{Foooo}
\subsection{Babar}
\subsection{Babaz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are no newbie, so you could at least look at the terminal output or check the log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks, it lead me to the solution. But even if I'm glad to see that you consider me as a non-newbie, I am used to debug LaTeX-programming related stuff, but not LaTeX-formatting stuff that still keeps a fair amount of mystery to me… and it has not even crossed my mind that the logs might help here.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment of Ulrike (sorry, I am used to debug LaTeX-programming related stuff, but not LaTeX-formatting stuff… and it has not even crossed my mind that the logs might help), I realized that the terminal was producing a warning `Warning: bookmark level for unknown subsectionNotIndented defaults to 0.`. After a bit of googling, I quickly [found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244263/bookmark-issues) the solution: I need to add `\@namedef{toclevel@subsectionNotIndented}{2}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,colorlinks]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\firstname{Foo}
\familyname{bar}
\title{My title}
\address{Adress}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{subsectionNotIndented}
\@namedef{toclevel@subsectionNotIndented}{2}
\newcommand\subsectionNotIndented{%
  \@startsection{subsectionNotIndented}{2}
  {\z@}% Left indentation
  {2mm plus 1mm minus 1mm}% Space above
  {2mm plus 1mm minus 1mm}% space after label
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries\color{color1}}% font for
}
\@namedef{toclevel@subsubsectionNotIndented}{3}
\newcounter{subsubsectionNotIndented}
\newcommand\subsubsectionNotIndented{%
  \@startsection{subsubsectionNotIndented}{3}
  {0mm}% Left indentation
  {1mm plus .5mm minus .5mm}% Space above
  {1mm plus .5mm minus .5mm}% space after label
  {\normalfont\normalsize\color{color1}}% font for
}
\newcommand\subsectionNotIndentedmark[1]{}
\newcommand\subsubsectionNotIndentedmark[1]{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\maketitle

\section{Foo}
\subsection{Bar}
\subsection{Baz}

\section{Fooo}
\subsection{Baar}
\subsection{Baaz}

\section{MyFoo}
\subsectionNotIndented{MyBarr}
\subsubsectionNotIndented{MySubBarr}
\subsubsectionNotIndented{MySubBarrr}

\subsectionNotIndented{MyBazz}
\subsubsectionNotIndented{MySuubBarr}
\subsubsectionNotIndented{MySuubBarrr}

\section{Foooo}
\subsection{Babar}
\subsection{Babaz}

\end{document}
```